# PHP begin time and end time issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Test extends Controller {    
public function start_process(){  
     $begin_time = time();  
     echo $begin_time ;   // suppose it shows 1318412333
    // statement 1   
    // statement 2   
    // statement 3   
    // statement 4   
    // statement 5   
    // statement 6   
    // some more code

    $this->end_process($begin_time);  
    }

    public function end_process($begin_time){  
    $end_time = time();
    echo $begin_time . " " . $end_time;  
    }
}
```

Now when i echo in end_process function . Suppose end_time is 1318412390 i get begin_time same as end_time. Why does this happen.. How do get the original begin_time which was set in first function

Comment: You mean it will echo 1318412333 1318412390 1318412390?

Comment: Add `sleep(1);` between begin and end then check the result again.

Comment: ya it will 1318412333 1318412390 1318412390

Comment: If this is your original code it really does not make sense. I assume you are not using some class member variable in your original code?

Comment: Impossible. This can't be the actual code you're using. Show us the class as well.

Comment: @Nin : I have added class in the code .. This is not my original code .. but its similar to my original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php). It gives you a more accurate time reading for when execution time is less than a second.

**Edit**

`microtime(true);` will return the time as a float so it's easier to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

time(); gives you seconds, but what you're actually dealing with is fractions thereof. As spider pointed out, you want to go with microtime()!

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

// -- do something --

// calulcate duration between $start and now
$duration = microtime(true) - $start;
// print in the format 1.2345 for better reading
printf("took %0.4d seconds", $duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
class test {

    public function start_process(){  
        $begin_time = time();  
        echo $begin_time . "<br>";   // suppose it shows 1318412333
        // statement 1   
        // statement 2   
        // statement 3   
        // statement 4   
        // statement 5   
        // statement 6   
        // some more code
        sleep(1);
        $this->end_process($begin_time);  
    }

    public function end_process($begin_time){  
        $end_time = time();
        echo $begin_time . " <br> " . $end_time;  
    }
}

$test = new test();
$test->start_process();

?>
```

My result is

```
1318415493
1318415493
1318415494
```

Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code:

```
$test = new Test();
    $test->start_process();

    class Test  {    
    public function start_process(){  
         $begin_time = microtime(true);  
         echo $begin_time . ' ';   // suppose it shows 1318412333 
         for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) { 
           //just some delay as if the script is doing something
         }
        $this->end_process($begin_time);  
        }

        public function end_process($begin_time){  
        $end_time = microtime(true);
        echo $begin_time . " " . $end_time;  
        }
    }
```

You'll see that is works, so that piece of code isn't the problem. The error must be in some other part of the code.

Comment: I do agree with you .. this piece of code it does work.. but you have used sleep(1) in your code.. which will create the time difference.. How do get time difference without using sleep() ..

Comment: Ah, there could be no time difference (or less than a second) so then use microtime() as suggested above. I'll edit my code so you can see